# Session State not saved

Tags: c#, asp.net-session

I want to save a string in session with a string key. I do it like;

```
Session["sessionkey"]=",2011,2012";
```

There is a ajax request sequence in my mvc application that is used for a wizard. There works partial views. I request to a controller that saves the session and uses the session. But after a new request I can't find the session with key "sessionkey". I'm not pro in asp.net mvc I'm learning. Do I miss something?

Comment: Do you have cookies enabled? Session relies on cookies.

Comment: Thanks. I used use cookies options. I did enable it. It worked when I requested different controller method. But I can't get the session value when I sent request to same controller. That's a ajax request with partial views.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something like this in your web.config

```
<system.web>
      <sessionState mode="InProc"          
                    timeout="20"/>
      </sessionState>
   </system.web>
```